# "This Class Is Not Key Value Coding-Compliant For The Key" Is There A Way To Trace This Error?

Tags: viewcontroller, xcode4.4

I get this error when I run my project:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController 0x6a38b60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key detailDescriptionLabel.'
```

But the thing is I don't have any detailDescriptionLabel Outlet in my ViewController, neither in my XIB. I only have one XIB, and I add other things to my XIB, in code.
Is there some way to find where is this error or what link I need to delete? I'm trying to debug my project, but I can't find where is this error from...

I'm using XCODE 4.4

This is my project: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/63305852/GRB.zip)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You hooked up something in the wrong way in your XIB or storyboard.
Go to your storyboard/XIB and in the `Document Outline` right click on the view controller; you should be able to see the details of it with all the connections. Probably, you'll see the bad connection with the warning sign, so just remove it and redo it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check out if you haven't removed the default label included with the DetailViewController, its name is 'detailDescriptionLabel'. 
Remove it and it should work.